# Edittext "lag" android

Tags: android, android-edittext

The first time i focus an edittext view i notice a lag of one or two seconds before i can write anything in the textbox.

I notice this behavior even on an app without any code more than what's nessecary to initialize the application.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any applications you installed that effect text editing? Such as a custom keyboard?

Comment: Are you debugging?  Executing the application in debug mode adds a very noticeable amount of latency to the emulator's response time

Answer (score 6):

I've INSTANTLY fixed this issue for me; I saw in the DDMS that a lot of redraw's and recalculations were occurring while entering text, and a lot of info about RelativeLayouts were being called. So, I checked my layout; i had some Multi-Line EditText's who were direct children of a RelativeLayout. So, I wrapped those up into a Linear Layout, and specified my desired width/height at the LinearLayout, not each EditText.

Guess what? It totally fixed it!!

(below, some code... keep in mind, this is just an approximation. Don't try and copy/paste)

**BEFORE:**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AFTER:**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Wrapped my EditText's into a LinearLayout, and relinquished dynamic layout controls to the LinearLayout.
It was an amazing and instant improvement.

Comment: The solution really worked... another example will be at https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/solved-android-edittext-lag.html

Comment: How did you use ddms to view all that information about redraws and RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator?

This is common when you are using the emulator regardless of debug mode or not...at least from my (limited) experience so far. Try your app out on a real phone and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off USB debugging and uninstalled a few keyboards. Seems to work fine now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Edit AndroidManifest:

My old code

```
< uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

My new code

```
< uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

I just removed the targetSdkVersion and the lag went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the symptoms were the same, a delay occurred to present the keyboard and when typing the letters were gradually appearing.
The solution is because I had put a Background image in the RelativeLayout, when I did a test taking the background worked out and stopped the delay, so I entered an online site that reduces photos and then reduced from 93kb to 50kb and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the *background-drawable for the activity (as dialog) on XML*, it was too heavy. changing it, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the lag was because of the heavy serialised objects I used to pass in Intent `putExtra()` of activities in the app. Those would continue to stay in the memory and cause the problem.