# All my EditTexts in my app has a delay (short freeze) when clicking them before I can type

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app I'm using `EditText` in a few different places. However, **whenever I click any of these EditText's**, the soft keyboard appears and then there is a **short delay where it seems like everything freezes** for about one or two seconds before I can type.

Same thing happens when I am done typing and click the back button, the soft keyboard disappears and then there is a white square instead where it took place and it again freezes for one or two seconds.

I have searched for it and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069855/edittext-lag-android), I tried it but didn't change anything. What can be the cause for this and how can I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weekTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/PaleBlack"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/desiredHoursContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/weekTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weekTextView">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/desiredHoursEditText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/desiredHoursEditText"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/desired_hours"
        android:textColor="@color/PaleBlack"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desiredHoursEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/unitTextView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/unitTextView"
        android:background="@drawable/main_border_square"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/PaleBlack"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:text="h"
        android:textColor="@color/PaleBlack"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you testing it - phone, emulator? if not already done, try testing it in a bare bones project with just one `EditText`

Comment: I am testing on my phone and a tablet. I just made a new project and put nothing but an EditText in the layout, and it seems to work fine. **EDIT** I pasted the code for my layout, have a look if you will

Comment: have try without set text-color and background.

Comment: Tried, did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following line to my activity in the manifest, not sure why tho.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```